# How can you create a chat gallery to talk one-on-one with another person?

Tags: discussion, chat

How can you get to talk with another person you're having a problem with? This is to solve the problem of course and also to make sure there isn't any unnecessary down voting on random questions and answers.

Comment: A chat galley?? You meant a channel surely? Galley is a ship...

Comment: Considering our main room is The [Bridge](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bridge), a smaller temporary room being called a [galley](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Galley) doesn't sound too far off. :P

Comment: I know this is tangential to your question but I really wonder what you mean by "also to make sure there isn't any unnecessary down voting on random questions and answers"

Answer (score 6):

Search for the user in the [chat user page](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users), and then go to their chat profile. Once you're there click on the "start a new room with this user" button. That will create a chat room and should send the user an invitation to join the room.

Answer (score 4):

To add on to what @wipqozn said, only moderators have the ability to create truly invisible chat rooms that only people invited (as well as any other moderators in the Stack Exchange network) can read and write in it. Note that a normal user like yourself can create gallery chat rooms, and while others may not be able to write in it, they can certainly read it. Beware of what you say in there.

Also, emphasising what @GraceNote said below, this is for

## **Moderation purposes only!**

Comment: To tack onto this perhaps the most important point missing here: moderators will not do this on user's behalf. It's a motion strictly for moderator purposes only, such as when they might have to discuss private details with a user. We do not permit private rooms wherein normal users can just hide out beyond what eyes can see.